# Ihara zeta function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, zeta-functions, riemann-zeta-function

Is there a natural connection between the Ihara zeta function of a graph,
and (for instance) the Riemann zeta function of certain varieties over finite fields ? 
 Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can construct a graph the resembles natural numbers, but I doubt it...

Answer (score 6):

RH for the Ihara zeta function will correspond to the graph being Ramanujan (if the graph is (q+1)-regular).

The zeta function for varieties over finite fields is more related to Ruelle's zeta function, but you can see Ihara zeta function as a special instance of it, using symbolic dynamics representation of a walk in your graph as a dynamical system.

A nice reference for this material is Audrey Terras' book - "Zeta Functions of Graphs: A Stroll through the Garden"

Comment: Ah, thanks. Are there other zeta functions for graphs which relate more directly to the Riemann zeta of varieties over finite fields ?